# list full partition information from powershell, just like from Disk Management

Tags: windows-10, powershell, system-info

If I launch **diskmgmt.msc**, I end up full info on my partitions, including size and present file system (ntfs, fat32, etc...)
[image]

This has all the info I need to plan a Linux Mint multiboot.  But I'd much rather have the info in text form, because I can't run the diskmanager while installing Linux.

**Q: What can I use to list both what file system is being used, as well as size, for each partition?**

`diskpart list volume` looks like it would have done the trick, but not found in Windows 10.

`get-partition` gives me size, but w.o. telling me much else:

```
   DiskPath: \\?\scsi#disk&ven_&prod_liteonit_lcs-256#4&2bcd8382&0&040000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                        Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                        ---- ----
1                            1048576                                     450 MB Recovery
2                            472907776                                   100 MB System
3                            577765376                                    16 MB Reserved
4                C           594542592                                  95.5 GB Basic
5                            103135838208                                450 MB Recovery
6                H           103607697408                             107.32 GB Basic
7                I           218846199808                              14.65 GB Basic
8                            234574839808                              20.01 GB Recovery


   DiskPath: \\?\scsi#disk&ven_&prod_st1000lm024_hn-m#4&2bcd8382&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                        Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                        ---- ----
1                D           1048576                                  465.75 GB Basic
2                E           500101545984                             301.69 GB Basic
3                F           878569324544                              15.62 GB Basic
4                G           895346540544                              97.66 GB Basic


   DiskPath:
\\?\usbstor#disk&ven_lexar&prod_usb_flash_drive&rev_1100#j8xx88thzzmnl0erdivy&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                        Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                        ---- ----
1                J           1048576                                    7.47 GB Basic
```

**get-volume** looks quite promising, except it doesn't me the size of the unformatted partitions:

```
DriveLetter FileSystemLabel FileSystem DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- --------------- ---------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
I                                      Fixed     Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
            Restore         NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                       7.2 GB  20.01 GB
            Recovery        NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                     76.66 MB    450 MB
K                                      CD-ROM    Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
C                           NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                     59.37 GB   95.5 GB
J           LINUX MINT      FAT32      Removable Healthy      OK                      5.56 GB   7.45 GB
                            NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                    146.66 MB    450 MB
H           DATA            NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                    107.03 GB 107.32 GB
E           Data2           NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                    142.64 GB 301.69 GB
D           Data1           NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                     93.58 GB 465.75 GB
F                                      Fixed     Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
G                                      Fixed     Healthy      Unknown                     0 B       0 B
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet would list all properties of all volumes, each particular volume together with corresponding partition:

```
Get-Volume | ForEach-Object {
    $VolObj = $_
    $ParObj = Get-Partition | Where-Object { $_.AccessPaths -contains $VolObj.Path }
    if ( $ParObj ) {
        $VolObj | Select-Object -Property *
        '------------'
        $ParObj | Select-Object -Property *
        '----------------------------------'
    }
}
```

Try combining desired properties in a custom object or simply to standard output e.g. as

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Volume | ForEach-Object {
    $VolObj = $_
    $ParObj = Get-Partition | Where-Object { $_.AccessPaths -contains $VolObj.Path }
    if ( $ParObj ) {
        '{0,2} {1,2} {2,6} {3,20} {4,20} {5,2} {6}' -f $VolObj.DriveLetter,
            $ParObj.DiskNumber,
            $VolObj.FileSystem, 
            $VolObj.Size, 
            $VolObj.SizeRemaining,
            $ParObj.PartitionNumber,
            $VolObj.FileSystemLabel

    }
}

 D  0   NTFS        1000202039296         900793958400  1 DataDisk
    1   NTFS            366997504             83173376  1 Rezervováno systémem
 C  1   NTFS         119664537600          69979885568  2
```

Comment: hezky, nice use of `-f`, if you don't like [Format-Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6) with *Calculated Property*

Answer (score 0):

JosefZ's answer upgraded:

```
$disksObject = @()
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='3'" | ForEach-Object {
    $VolObj = $_
    $ParObj = Get-Partition | Where-Object { $_.AccessPaths -contains $VolObj.DeviceID }
    if ( $ParObj ) {
        $disksobject += [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            DiskID = $([string]$($ParObj.DiskNumber) + "-" + [string]$($ParObj.PartitionNumber)) -as [string]
            Mountpoint = $VolObj.Name
            Letter = $VolObj.DriveLetter
            Label = $VolObj.Label
            FileSystem = $VolObj.FileSystem
            'Capacity(GB)' = ([Math]::Round(($VolObj.Capacity / 1GB),2))
            'FreeSpace(GB)' = ([Math]::Round(($VolObj.FreeSpace / 1GB),2))
            'Free(%)' = ([Math]::Round(((($VolObj.FreeSpace / 1GB)/($VolObj.Capacity / 1GB)) * 100),0))
        }
    }
}
$disksObject | Sort-Object DiskID | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You can modify drive filtering with DriveTypes based on your liking. Currently it shows only Fixed drives.

Output example:

```
DiskID Mountpoint               Letter Label                   FileSystem Capacity(GB) FreeSpace(GB) Free(%)
------ ----------               ------ -----                   ---------- ------------ ------------- -------
0-1    C:\                      C:     Windows                 NTFS                 80         38.18      48
1-1    E:\                      E:     DATA                    NTFS                 30         25.52      85
2-1    E:\DATA\SQL\SY0\                SY0                     NTFS                 20         18.83      94
3-1    E:\DATA\SQL\SL0\                E:\DATA\SQL\SL0         NTFS                 70         56.31      80
4-1    E:\DATA\SQL\ST0\                E:\DATA\SQL\ST0         NTFS                 40         35.52      89
5-1    E:\DATA\SQL\SD0\                E:\DATA\SQL\SD0         NTFS                140        110.16      79
6-1    E:\DATA\SQL_Support\SS0\        E:\DATA\SQL_Support\SS0 NTFS                140        127.97      91
```